# Do oriented null cobordant manifolds admit spin structures?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, spin-geometry

Let $M$ be an oriented null cobordant manifold.

Since $M$ is oriented its first Stiefel-Whitney class vanishes.

Since $M$ is null cobordant all of its Stiefel-Whitney numbers vanish.

Is it known if this implies that the second Stiefel-Whitney class vanishes so that $M$ admits a spin structure? Or are there known counterexamples?

Comment: But how is the accepted answer consistent with the OP's "Since  is null cobordant all of its Stiefel-Whitney numbers vanish " ? you pick a non-spin manifold  with a  second stiefel whitney class not vanish...?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No: Take your favourite orientable non-spin manifold $M$. Then $M\times S^1$ also does not admit a spin structure as the second stiefel whitney class does not vanish. But this manifold is nullbordant: It is the boundary of $M\times D^2$, where $D^2$ is the disc.

Comment: But how is your example consistent with the OP's "Since  is null cobordant all of its Stiefel-Whitney numbers vanish " ? you pick a non-spin manifold  with a  second stiefel whitney class not vanish...?

Comment: Classes are not numbers

Comment: yes, classes are not numbers. But they are related: how does a second stiefel whitney class relate to its stiefel whitney number?